# How to avoid over-counting in this SQL query?

Tags: sql

Trains table is:

```
trains:
tid | dept | dest | time
 3    SF      LA     8
 33   SF      LA     10
```

Passengers table is:

```
pass:
pid | dept | dest | time
100   SF     LA     7
101   SF     LA     8
102   SF     LA     9
```

I'm trying to find the number of passengers who boarded a train. My current query is:

```
select tid,trains.dept,trains.dest, count(distinct pid)
from
trains inner join pass
on
trains.dept=pass.dept
and
trains.dest=pass.dest
and
trains.time>=pass.time
group by
tid,trains.dept,trains.dest
```

The query is wrong because it's re-counting passengers who already left for the destination on an earlier train. How to avoid this over-counting?

Desired Results:

```
tid number_of_passengers
3   2
33  1
```

The result I'm getting:

```
tid number_of_passengers
3    2
33   3
```

For example,
tid 3 is correctly displaying only 2 passengers who boarded, while tid 33(Same destination) is wrongly displaying 2+1(the 2 is from tid 3).

Comment: Sample data, desired results would really help.  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added sample data.

Comment: `trains.time>=pass.time` should not be `trains.time=pass.time`?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that someone boards the next train.  You can get the "next" train using a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select t.tid
        from trains t
        where t.dept = p.dept and t.dest = p.dest and t.time >= p.time
        order by t.time asc
        limit 1
       ) as tid
from pass p;
```

Once you have this information, the summary by train is just an aggregation:

```
select tid, count(*)
from (select p.*,
             (select t.tid
              from trains t
              where t.dept = p.dept and t.dest = p.dest and t.time >= p.time
              order by t.time
              limit 1
             ) as tid
      from pass p
     ) p
group by tid;
```

Comment: Shouldnt be `t.time >= p.time`? acording to OP passanger 7 and 8 leave on the 8 train

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Yup.  People can't get on trains that  have already left the station.  Thank you.